# How to make constraint on Dates

Tags: oracle, date, jpa, jakarta-ee

I come the to problem with creating database table over JPA. I have some atributes for creating database table together with two fields for Date. I need to make sure, that input for DateEnd must be bigger than input for DateStart

```
@Column(name="START")
private LocalDate dateStart
@Column(name="END")
private LocalDate dateEnd
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on entity level, you should define your custom costraint with its `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator` implementation. See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-validator) for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged it as an "Oracle" question, and if you want to do that in the database, a *natural* choice would be the CHECK constraint.

Here's an example (note that the date literal's format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'):

```
SQL> create table test (id number, date_start date, date_end date);

Table created.

SQL> alter table test add constraint ch_test_date check (date_start <= date_end);

Table altered.

SQL> insert into test values (1, date '2018-03-19', date '2018-05-10');

1 row created.

SQL> update test set date_end = date '2010-01-02' where id = 1;
update test set date_end = date '2010-01-02' where id = 1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_TEST_DATE) violated


SQL> insert into test values (1, date '2018-03-19', date '2018-01-02');
insert into test values (1, date '2018-03-19', date '2018-01-02')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_TEST_DATE) violated


SQL>
```